# Where is the return object stored?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I generally understand how a function returns an object by value. But I wanted to understand it on the lower level. Assembly level if reasonable.

I understand this this code

```
ClassA fun(){
    ClassA a;
    a.set(...);
    return a;
}
```

is transformed internally to

```
void fun(Class& ret){
    ClassA a;
    a.set(...);
    ret.ClassA::ClassA(a);
}
```

Which effectively call the copy constructor on the return value.

I also understand that there are some optimizations (like NRVO) that could generate the following code avoiding the copy constructor.

```
void fun(Class& ret){
    ret.set(...);
}
```

However my question is a bit more basic. It doesn't really have to do with Objects in specific. It could be even primitive types.

Lets say we have this code:

```
int fun(){
   return 0;
}
int main(){
    fun();
}
```

My question is where is the return object stored in memory.

If we look at the stack... There is the stack frame of `main` and then the stack frame of `fun`. Is the return object stored in some address like maybe between the two stack frames? Or maybe it is stored somewhere in the `main` stack frame (and possibly that's the address which is passed by reference in the generated code).

I have thought about it and the second one seems more practical however I don't understand how the compiler know how much memory to push in the stack frame of `main`? Does it calculate what is the largest return type and push that even though there could be some wasted memory? Or is it done dynamically, it allocates that space only before the function is called?

Comment: Depends on the compiler, but you can always [look at its assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/JztY5G).

Comment: By the way, `ret.ClassA::ClassA(a);` doesn't compile. This is how it should be written: `new (&ret) ClassA(a);`.

Comment: Strong implementation detail.  In general the compiler will try to return anything in CPU registers.  If it does not fit then it will have the caller reserve space on its stack frame and pass a pointer to this storage.  The likely scenario in this case.  Just try it on your own compiler, ask it to generate an assembly listing.  You'll have a fact instead of a guess.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The C++ language specification does not specify these low level details. They are specified by each C++ implementation, and the actual implementation details vary from platform to platform.

In nearly every case, a return value that's a simple, native type gets returned in a certain, designated, CPU register. When a function returns a class instance, the details vary, depending on the implementation. There are several common approaches, but the typical case would be the caller being responsible for allocating sufficient space for the return value on the stack, before calling the function and passing an additional hidden parameter, to the function, where the function is going to copy the returned value (or construct it, in case of RVO). Or, the parameter is implicit, and the function can find the space, on the stack, for the return value itself, after the call's stack frame.

It's also possible that a given C++ implementation will still use a CPU register to return classes that are small enough to fit into a single CPU register. Or, perhaps, a few CPU registers are reserved for returning slightly bigger classes.

The details vary, and you will need to consult the documentation for your C++ compiler, or your operating system, to determine the specific details that apply to you.

Comment: Normally the calling convention is specified by the platform ABI, which may be OS-dependent but is not strictly speaking part of the OS, nor is it up to the compiler. Of course, documentation might be found anywhere (if you're lucky) or nowhere (if you're not) but searching for an ABI is often a good start.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is ABI specific but generally the calls are compiled with an hidden parameter which is the pointer to the memory that the function should use, like you said suppose the function is compiled as

```
void fun(Class& ret){
    ClassA a;
    a.set(...);
    ret.ClassA::ClassA(a);
}
```

Then at call site you will have something like

```
Class instance = fun();
fun(instance);
```

Now this makes the caller reserve `sizeof(Class)` bytes on the stack and pass that address to the function so that `fun` can "fill" that space.

This is no different from how the stack frame of the caller would reserve space for its own locals, the only difference is that the address to one of its locals is passed to `fun`.

Mind that if `sizeof(Class)` is less than the size of a register (or a couple of registers) it is totally possible that value is returned directly inside them.

Answer (score 4):

In the following code:

```
int fun()
{
   return 0;
}
```

The return value is stored in a register.  On intel architectures, this will usually be `ax` (16-bit), or `eax` (32-bit), or `rax` (64-bit).  (Historically known as *the accumulator*.)

If the return value was a pointer or a reference to an object, it would still be returned through that register.

If the return value is larger than a machine word, then the ABI (Application Binary Interface) may require another register to be used to hold the high-order word.  So, if you are returning a 32-bit quantity on a 16-bit architecture, `dx:ax` will be used.  (And so on for larger quantities in bigger architectures.)

Larger return values are passed by other means, like the `void fun(Class& ret)` mechanism that you are already aware of.

Passing return values via the accumulator register is very efficient and it is a somewhat strong convention, almost all ABIs that I have seen require it.

Comment: This is really misleading. Regardless of optimization, translation units must be able to call functions compiled inside other translation units, even if the two translation units have been compiled with different optimization settings. So optimization can only modify calling conventions for functions only visible within the translation unit they are defined in (i.e. `static`). For externally visible functions, the platform ABI rules the calling convention independent of optimization settings.

Comment: @rici what is misleading?  My entire post, or some specific point that I am making?

Comment: The last two paragraphs where you suggest that optimization level affects thw calling convention.

Comment: @rici okay, my memory might be betraying me, perhaps you need to explicitly specify a specific calling convention like `fastcall` for those optimizations to happen. I will remove those parts from my answer.

Comment: Most compilers let you specify non-standard calling conventions but you need to do so in the header file so that both caller and callee produce interoperable code. Whether it us an optimization or not is a matter of opinion, but it is certainly not a *compiler* optimization since it is explicitly requested by the code.

Comment: @rici Right.  However, in light of this, perhaps Sam Varshavchik's answer needs the same clarifications.

Comment: @MikeNakis: yes rici is correct. Think about the fact that if optimizations would be able to change calling conventions arbitrarily you would possibly have an object file with `foo(int x)` which expects the argument into a register and another object file which calls `foo` by passing it on the stack. Since compiled code is not aware of what's happening then the  only choice is being sure that everything is compiled respecting the ABI contract from both sides.

Comment: @Jack yes, I know, and I have fixed my answer.  But since we are discussing it, Isn't the compiler free to do whatever it pleases with functions that are private to a compilation unit? (`static` functons outside of classes, private methods of classes)  Also, isn't there such a thing as "whole program optimizations"?

Comment: @MikeNakis: Even with whole program optimization, functions with external linkage are exported so that they could (in theory) be referenced by an external library, including one loaded at runtime with a dynamic loader. So the only case in which a compiler could optimize a calling convention is a  function without external linkage, in which case the compiler is free to do what it pleases. In that case the most common optimization is partial or complete inlining.