# where is the value on each iteration of this recursive function getting stored?

Tags: c++

How does this recursive function work in a return statement - where is the value on each iteration getting stored? ex.: `val = 5`. when the function completes, the factorial is returned as 120.I'm calling the function with `cout<<factorial(5)     <<endl;`

```
// recursive factorial function.
int factorial(int val)
{
    if (val > 1)
    {
        return (factorial(val-1) * val);//gets called 4 times
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Wherever return values are stored. This will probably be a CPU register. Good reading (and probably answers your question): [Where is the return object stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910764/where-is-the-return-object-stored)

Comment: In the case of `cout<<factorial(5) <<endl;` a good optimizing compiler compute the result at compile time and generate code for `cout<<120 <<endl;`

Comment: Examples: https://godbolt.org/z/DDPrs2 note the `mov     esi, 120` in the assembled `main` functions in gcc and clang. That's all that's left of `factorial(5)`. So long as the behaviour described by the code is unchanged, [the compiler can do anything it wants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: It isn't simple

Answer (score 1):

Modern CPUs use a stack for handling local variables and return addresses for functions (this was prompted by Algol and it's successors, to be able to handle recursion cleanly). Each currently executing function gets a *activation record* containing local variables (including arguments) and return address allocated on the stack. The values you ask about are among the values in the activation record (it includes not only variables you define, but also temporary values the compiler creates for it's own purposes).

A way to see what is going on is to tickle your compiler into writing assembly language (perhaps even adding debugging information, it's text can help deciphering the assembly language by giving pointers to the source). E.g.:

`clang++ -S -g factorial.cc`

gives `factorial.s`.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the other answers, I would like to add that on a more abstract level, each call to a function creates an additional activation record on the runtime stack. In the case of a recursive function, you will have multiple activation records for each recursive call. In your example where we want `5!`, some representative pseudo-code of this portion of the runtime stack might look something like (from bottom to top):

`int factorial(int val = 1){ /*returning 1*/ }`

`int factorial(int val = 2){ /*returning 2 * factorial(1)*/ }`

`int factorial(int val = 3){ /*returning 3 * factorial(2)*/ }`

`int factorial(int val = 4){ /*returning 4 * factorial(3)*/ }`

`int factorial(int val = 5){ /*returning 5 * factorial(4)*/ }`

Then, once you reach the base case, the process is completed going back down the stack (in the case where `val = 1`, you return 1; now when `val = 2`, you can return `2 * 1 = 2`; then when `val = 3`, you can return `3 * 2 = 6`; then return `4 * 6 = 24`; finally return `5 * 24 = 120`); and, as each return is executed, that respective activation record is popped off the stack until the final answer is returned to the location where it was called.

Comment: Yes I thought the function was executing a second set of times. Thanks for your post.