# Why is C++ copy constructor called twice?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have some code that returns a class object by value and the copy constructor is being called more than I thought it would. This seems to be how the g++ compiler does things but I'm not sure why. Say I have this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "constructor" << endl; }
    A(const A& other) { cout << "copy constructor" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "destructor" << endl; }
};

A f()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "before f()\n";
    A a = f();
    cout << "after f()\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with constructor elision turned off

```
g++ test.cpp -fno-elide-constructors
```

it outputs this:

> before f()
> constructor
> copy constructor
> destructor
> copy constructor
> destructor
> after f()
> destructor

So the copy constructor is called twice. I can see why the copy constructor would be called when copying the return value of `f()` into the variable `a` but why again?

I've read about C++ compilers returning temporary objects from functions but I don't understand the point of that. Even with elision turned off it seems unnecessary to create a temporary object for every function return value.

#### Update

Just to be super clear here, I'm not surprised that the copy constructor is being called. I expect that since I turned off elision. What I'm confused about is why the copy constructor needs to be called twice. It seems like once should be enough to copy the result from `f()` into `a`.

Comment: You told it not to Elide and you don’t have a move ctor. What is the surprise here?

Comment: There are three `A` objects, there are three constructors, and three destructors.  They are not elided, because you've disabled eliding.

Comment: I'm not surprised that a copy constructor is being called, I'm surprised that it's being called twice.

Comment: Assuming your compiler predates C++17, the semantics of `return A()` in `f()` is to return a copy of a default-constructed object to the caller and the semantics of `A a = f()` in `main()` is to copy the returned object (i.e. copy the copy of the default-constructed object) into `a`.    Copy elision is permitted but not required - and, since you have told your compiler not to elide copies, it copies twice.   In C++17 and later, mandatory copy elision comes into play according to the standard (but, I suppose, may or may not be affected by telling the compiler not to elide copies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Pre-C++17

In Pre-C++17 standard there was **non-mandatory copy elison**, so by using the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag you are **disabling** the return value optimization and some other optimizations where copies are elided.

This is what is happening in your program:

1. First due to the return statement `return A();` an object is constructed using the **default constructor** `A::A()`.
2. Next, a copy of that default constructed object is returned to the caller. This is done using the copy constructor `A::A(const A&)`. Hence you get the first copy constructor call output.
3. Finally, due to the statement `A a = f();` which is **copy initialization**, the object named `a` is created as a copy of that returned value using  the copy constructor `A::A(const A&)`. Hence you get the second copy constructor call output.

```
//--v----------------------->1st copy constructor called due to this(return by value) 
    A f()
    {
//-------------vvv---------->default constructor called due to this
        return A();
    }
//--vvvvvvvvv--------------->2nd copy constructor called due to this(copy initialization)
    A a = f();
```

---

##### C++17

In C++17(and onwards), due to [**mandatory copy elison**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), you will not get any copy constructor call output. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sQ8rn67NloFQM4Do).

Comment: @eerorika I have updated that line so that people don't misinterpret it. I never said(nor it was my intention to imply) that there was any change in C++11. I guess this happens sometimes when you're not a native english speaker(as english is not my native language). I have updated that line so that there is no confusion(if there was any).

Comment: Point #2 above says `Next, a copy of that default constructed object is returned to the caller`. Where is this object being stored if it's not in `a`?

Comment: @d512 It is an implementation detail. That is, the standard doesn't specify this. Depending upon the implementation the details vary. For your follow up question you can refer to [Where is the return object stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910883/15545927).

Comment: @d512 In case you're wondering why the copy constructor is called for the 2nd time, it is because the statement `A a = f();` is **copy initialization**. And so `a` is created as a copy of the object returned by the call to `f()`. And since you've disabled optimization using the flag, you get the 2nd copy constructor call. I have mentioned the same in my answer.

Comment: Okay, so the compiler is probably creating its own temporary variable and putting the return value of `f()` into that variable, then copying it over to `a`.

Comment: @d512 Basically yes, that is one possible scenario. If the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910883/15545927) answer doesn't answer your follow up question, you can ask a separate question also.

Answer (score 5):

It's because pre C++17, compilers were not mandated to elide the copies. If you *do* turn on compiling this as C++17 or later, there will only be one constructor call - even if you use `-fno-elide-constructors`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/znrhfPK9j)

The instances in C++14 with `-fno-elide-constructors` are created like this:

```cpp
A // 2:nd (1:st copy)
f()
{
    return A();
    //     1:st
}

    A a = f();
//  3:rd (2:nd copy)
```

If you instead `return {};`, you can skip the first temporary instance and only get one copy:

```cpp
A // 1:st
f()
{
    return {};
    //    arg to ctor
}

    A a = f();
//  2:nd (1:st copy)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j45YxqddM)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that. Nonetheless, I'm still confused about why it calls the copy constructor twice for C++14 when elision is off. It seems like one copy should be enough.

Comment: @d512 I added more details